# Programs and downloads for a serverside mongo-dart DB

Tags: mongodb, download, dart

I have been programming with dart for a while now and after I tried LocalStorage, I wanted to start with a server-side mongo-dart app. So my question is:
What do I need as far as programs and downloads beside the Darteditor and Chromium?
I would be very happy about an answer.
Thanks in advance!
Karl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official MongoDB driver for Dart language mentiond on MongoDB site http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/.

However you can find a driver on GitHub by vadimtsushko:
https://github.com/vadimtsushko/mongo_dart

He also wrote tutorial http://blog.dartwatch.com/2012/03/building-client-server-dart-app-part-2.html

Hope it gives you something to start with.

Comment: Hi EngineerMike!
Thank you very much for your answer!
I am halfway through the blog and Chris Bucket wrote about an XMLhttpRequest. But the way he wrote the code it isn't accepted by my Dart Editor (M3).
Error message: "no such type"

Also the JSON isn't accepted.
Error message: "cannot resolve JSON"

I would be very glad if you could help me.
Thanks in advance!
Karl

Answer (score 1):

Here is a blog post I wrote awhile back that does a full stack example using mongodb and dart
http://financecoding.github.com/blog/2013/01/16/darting-a-full-stack/

The server side is still light, I'd suggest experimenting stream from  rikulo http://rikulo.org/projects/stream Might be a cleaner solution then rolling your own web server.

Have fun!